# How to remove Class name from exception message in python

Tags: python, exception

Here is the exception message in my python code:

```
Common.AnimalClass.NestedClass: Id is not found
```

I want to exclude the class name and just want to print the message like below:

```
Id is not found
```

I am new to python ,
How can I achieve this in python3?

```
    if not (is_id_present):
        self.log_step_status("FAIL", step_name)
        log_message = 'id is not found'
        raise TestCaseFailureError(log_message)

class TestCaseFailureError(Exception, vlogger):
"""Base Error class for tests"""

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.vlog('Message: {0}', args[0])
    Exception.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: can you post your piece of code ?

Comment: @VikasDamodar code is attached

Comment: You could catch the exception and return your custom message.

Comment: Can you please give a example of that ?